# RMI, Wildfly 10x, Spring: NoClassDefFoundError: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE

Tags: java, spring, wildfly, rmi

I have a Spring-Boot application, which exposes some of its Interfaces to other projects. The basic process of this has been tried and tested within the project structure very often, so this SHOULD not be a "simple" RMI issue like missing serialization or incorrect registry.

This project (coded on java7) and an older project (also java7) are to be deployed in a `wildfly 10.x` container.

Basically, it is planned that our old application talks to the Spring-Boot application to get specific data sets. When starting the application, the beans are instantiated correctly, and the basic connection seems to be okay. However, when using an entirely valid call, I get this:

> ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-5) UT005023: Exception handling request to /servlet/Foo: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/COMM_FAILURE

I tried debugging the application, and when using the offending method call, the remote class is being triggered and does its work normally, the return value is as expected and is being returned to the spring context.

The weird thing is this part of the Stack Trace:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/COMM_FAILURE
>       at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptorUtils.isCorbaConnectFailure(RmiClientInterceptorUtils.java:229)
>       at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptorUtils.isConnectFailure(RmiClientInterceptorUtils.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.isConnectFailure(RmiClientInterceptor.java:282)
>       at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.doInvoke(RmiClientInterceptor.java:347)
>       at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.invoke(RmiClientInterceptor.java:259)

because when I try to access `RmiClientInterceptorUtils.java:229`, Eclipse tells me that 229 is not a valid line number. This would lead me to believe that there is a versioning difference in Spring webMVC between server and client. This persisted, even after changing the version number (now using `3.2.8.RELEASE of spring-webmvc`), the errors persisted.

I checked if there might be a dependency problem, but CONN_FAILURE is part of `rt.jar` and should, as far as I know, be present in every java project. Further testing revealed that:

- Checked Exceptions are transferred normally
- primitive values (like boolean) are transferred correctly
- complex Objects cause the exception to be thrown

I'd appreciate any help with this matter, as I am at a loss to explain or correct this.
Thanks.

**NOTE**:
The general reason for the raised exception has been found - a class was missing the `Serializable` interface. This does, however, not answer the question why the `COMM_FAILURE` raised a NoClassDefFoundError, which is something I still would like to know.

Comment: This is very strange. It should indeed be part of the JDK, and it also shouldn't be used except in an RMI/IIOP context.

Comment: Well, it **is** used in in an RMI context. The thing is, there was a connection failure due to a missing `Serializable`interface, so checking for exceptions was done correctly, but during the check my container hit a `NoClassDefFoundError` which is why I am not removing this question- because knowing the reason for the underlying exception does not explain why there is a `NoClassDefFoundError`on a JDK class